# Generic JQuery Function?

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I'm using Jeditable to edit dozens of fields such as first_name, last_name, birthday, etc.

My problem is that I'm drowning in detail: I keep having to create a new selector such as `$('#edit_first_name').editable` or `$('#edit_birthday').editable` to making the field editable as well as create a bunch of SQL commands specific to each field to insert them once they're edited.

My question is: **Is there a way I can create something generic or OO in JQuery so that I don't don't have to endlessly create code that essentially does the same thing?**

My guess is I can create some "generic" function that will create `$('#edit_someField').editable` on the fly by feeding some JSON array, which was created by doing a SELECT on all field names I'm interested in. I imagine that's exactly what JQuery plugins do.

Any direction on how I can accomplish this would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

One solution I have come up with is to put the table, column name and id in the id value of whatever I want to edit.
For example, if I want to edit the first_name of id=6 on table Person, then in the id I will put `<span class="editable" id="Person:first_name:6">myFirstName</span>`. When I send the id to my `save.php` file, I use a `preg_split` to insert my data into the table.

Comment: You just want to select all the inputs and make them editable? are all of these fields `<input>` elements?

Comment: @ ImportedNoob: I think Elliot_Nelson and rlemon have got the idea of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark all your editable input fields with the class "editable". (Change to suit.)

```
$('.editable').each(function() {
  $(this).editable('mysaveurl.php');
});
```

That's all you need for the basic functionality. Obvious improvements can be made, depending on what else you need. For example, if you are using tooltips, stick them in the title attribute in your HTML, and use them when you call editable().

Your actual PHP/Ruby/whatever code on the server is just going to look at the id parameter coming in, and use that to save to the appropriate field in the database.

Comment: apparently the plugin does support this functionality a little better than i expected. ;)

Comment: It's worth noting that the actual Jeditable documentation actually recommends doing a simple $('.edit').editable(). This doesn't let you customize the tooltip, indicator, etc., by field though -- is that what you need to do? If so, looping through them like I do in my example should get you started.

Comment: Thanks @ Elliot Nelson. This is helpful info. I will try it out tonight.

Comment: How will the PHP/Ruby "know" what field to insert into? So far I have done something like `mysaveurl.php?editfirstname` so that the PHP knows that I'm talking about editing the first_name column of my entry with id 5.

Comment: I've never used Jeditable, but my understanding is that if the user enters "Elliot" into the "firstname" field, your server-side script will be called like so: mysaveurl.php?id=firstname&value=Elliot. You can use the "id" parameter for the field, and the "value" parameter for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a class to make them all editable, and using their id (or a attribute that you have attached to the tag) you can specify the field you are updating. 
Then just pass the field and the value to your DB.

*i don't know the plugin you are using*
but, assuming it has some sort of event handling in it...
something like this maybe?

```
$(".editable").editable({
      complete : function() {
            var _what = $(this).attr("id");
            var _with = $(this).val();
            $.post("yourPostPage.php",{what:_what, where:_where});
       }
});
```

Without knowing more about your environment I wouldn't be able to help further.

Comment: obviously `where:_where` was meant to be `with:_with`... my bad.

Comment: Thanks @ rlemon. I will look to use this for my other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way of assigning some common code to a bunch of objects is to either give all the objects the same class so you can just do this:

```
$(".myEditableFields").editable("enable");
```

This will call the editable add-on method for all objects in your page with `class="myEditableFields"`.

If you just have a list of IDs, you can just put them all in the single selector like this and they will each get called for the editable jQuery method:

```
$("#edit_first_name, #edit_birthday, #edit_last_name, #edit_address").editable("enable");
```

Sometimes, the easy way it to create a select that just identifies all editable fields within a parent div:

```
$("#editForm input").editable("enable");
```

This would automatically get all input tags inside the container div with `id=editForm`.

You can of course, collect common code into your own function in a traditional procedural programming pattern and just call that when needed like this:

```
function initEditables(sel) {
    $(sel).editable("enable");
    // any other initialization code you want here or event handlers you want to assign
}
```

And, then just call it like this as needed:

```
initEditables("#edit_first_name");
```

To help further, we would need to know more about what you're trying to do in your code and what your HTML looks like.